# MYSQL - Count consecutive identical values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which basically stores a list of points with reference of the player id who made that point.

My setup is:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isScore` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `points` (`id`, `player_id`, `game_id`, 
                  `score`, `isScore`,     `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
(16, 11, 60, 4, 0, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(17, 11, 60, 5, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(18, 12, 60, 6, 0, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(19, 12, 60, 7, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(20, 12, 60, 8, 0, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(21, 12, 60, 9, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(22, 8, 60, 10, 0, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(23, 8, 60, 11, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(24, 12, 60, 12, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(25, 12, 60, 13, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(26, 5, 60, 14, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(27, 12, 60, 15, 0, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(28, 12, 60, 16, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(29, 10, 60, 17, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39'),
(30, 10, 60, 18, 1, '2016-12-28 12:19:39', '2016-12-28 12:19:39');
```

Here's a SQLfiddle with this setup: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ca9f8

I want to get the number of maximum consecutive point made by a player for each player.

So in the sqlfiddle the result will be something like:

```
+-----------+------------------------+
| player_id | max_consegutive_points |
+-----------+------------------------+
|        12 |                      4 |
|         8 |                      2 |
|         5 |                      1 |
|        10 |                      2 |
+-----------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Next time add you setup here. Sometimes these support sites (as sqlfiddle) is out and in this situation your question would not have the data.

Comment: Please explain your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing some key points (no pun intended). For example: what is considered a consecutive identical value? You need to define if those values will be listed ordered by ID, created_at, ID+game_id, etc.

So let's say *the order is given by the ID*, because it may be autoincremental and it's only natural that points are inserted in the order they happened.

However, the answer will be to create a query with a counter variable (accum) that increases if the player is the same than the one in the former row, or resets to 1 if the player changes:

```
select 
    points.id,
    points.player_id,
    points.game_id,
    points.created_at,
    @counter:=IF(@playerid=points.player_id,@counter+1,1) as accum,
    @playerid:=points.player_id as current_player_id
from points,
    (select @counter:=1) c, 
    (select @playerid:=0) p
order by points.id
```

[<kbd>See SQLFiddle here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ca9f8/19)

Having the result of that table, and putting it into a view or temporary table that we may call "accums", you just need to do

```
SELECT player_id, max(accum) 
FROM accums 
GROUP BY player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(player_id), MAX(score) from points group by player_id;
```